# Large files upload

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a form with 5 asp.net upload controls. This is to allows user to upload 5 large files and submit. What would be the required steps to be able to achieve this? 
I have checked following configuration in IIS, Application Pool: Idle Timeout: 20min, Recyclicing regular time interval: 1740 min.
I've specified following in my web config file,

```
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

I am not able to to upload files when I try to upload files in all 5 upload controls.

Comment: What's the error u get?

Comment: System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out. and System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length exceeded

Answer (score 1):

There are a few reasons that may cause this, it's hard to know which without you letting us know which error you receive.

First: Notice that `maxRequestLength` is in KB whereas `maxAllowedContentLength` is in bytes.
Try increasing `maxRequestLength` like so: `maxRequestLength="2000000000"`

Second: Try a higher execution time such as `executionTimeout="999999"`

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2000000000" executionTimeout="999999"/>
```

Your current setup of `maxAllowedContentLength` allows 1024 MB. Make sure it isn't lower then the total size of all 5 files.

Comment: I am able to upload single large file but when I input in all 5 upload controls than I receive following errors, System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out. and System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length exceeded

Comment: Did you set all 3 attributes?

Comment: Yes I checked by setting up to 30 min idle time. How did you calculate, "Your current setup of maxAllowedContentLength allows 128 MB."  The figure "1073741824" which is mentioned is 1024 MB when you calculate.

Comment: Missed that, you are correct. Did you try uploading one big and a few small, to see if there is a time limit (e.g after 90 seconds it stops), or whether it's the *amount* of files?

Comment: I am able to upload smaller images in all upload controls.